# How to record multiple source webcam/ip cam video stream?

Tags: .net, video

i need to build a simple application who allow to record 2 or more video stream (max. 4) from ipcam / webcam, like a very simple surveillance system. 
What component (dll or similar) can you indicate to me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will be a multithreaded application.
in which each thread (worker) records from a source (usb video) to a destination (file stream).

you could do something like this (pseudo c#)
i hope it gives you a basic idea...

```
class Worker
{
    bool _record;
    ISource _source;
    IDestination _dest;

    public Worker(ISource source, IDestination dest)
    {
        _source = source;
        _dest = dest;
    }

    public void Record() 
    {
        lock(this)
            _record = true;
        pos = 0;
        while(_record)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[4096];
            len = _source.Read(pos, buffer);
            pos += len;
            dest.Write(buffer, len);
        }
    }

    public void Stop() 
    {
        lock (this)
            _record = false;
    }
}

class Program
{
   public static Main()
   {
      var w1 = new Worker(new UsbVideo(), new FileDestination());
      Thread.Start(w1.Record);

      ...

      Console.Readline();
      w1.Stop();
   }
}
```